# Unable to get mobx autorun, reaction, when to re-trigger more than one time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I have simple component that renders null, but should show iOS/Android alert when `shown` prop from notification store is changed to true, it works fine just one time using autorun / reaction / when from mobx and I can see through `spy` that `hideNotification` is also being fired correctly to set `shown` back to false, yet I can't re-trigger alert anymore.

Component

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react/native";
import { reaction } from "mobx";
import { Alert } from "react-native";

@inject("notification")
@observer
class Notification extends Component {
  // -- methods ------------------------------------------------------------- //
  componentDidMount() {
    reaction(
      () => this.props.notification.shown,
      () => {
        if (this.props.notification.shown)
          Alert.alert(
            this.props.notification.type,
            this.props.notification.message,
            [
              {
                text: "Close",
                onPress: this.props.notification.hideNotification
              }
            ]
          );
      }
    );
  }

  // -- render -------------------------------------------------------------- //
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default Notification;
```

Store

```
import { observable, action } from "mobx";

const ERROR = "notification/ERROR";
const SUCCESS = "notification/SUCCESS";

class NotificationStore {
  // -- store --------------------------------------------------------------- //
  @observable type = ERROR;
  @observable message = "";
  @observable shown = false;

  // -- actions ------------------------------------------------------------- //
  @action
  errorNotification(message) {
    this.type = ERROR;
    this.message = message;
    this.shown = true;
  }

  @action
  successNotification(message) {
    this.type = SUCCESS;
    this.message = message;
    this.shown = true;
  }

  @action
  hideNotification() {
    this.shown = false;
  }
}

export default NotificationStore;
```

Comment: Are you sure `autorun` does not work? [**It works for me**](http://jsbin.com/nucoqutaha/1/edit?js,console,output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the issue was that class functions were not binded correctly changing them to

```
@action
  errorNotification = (message) => {
    this.type = ERROR;
    this.message = message;
    this.shown = true;
  }
```

Solved this for me